# Python RSA library. Load private key file encrypted with a password

Tags: python, encryption, rsa

I exported the private key from a PFX file with this command:

```
openssl.exe pkcs12 -in "temp.pfx" -passin pass:secret -passout pass:1234 -out exported.key 2>$null 
openssl.exe rsa -in exported.key -passin pass:1234 -passout pass:1234 -des3 -out myprivatekey.pem -outform pem
```

I try to import it with the following python code, using the library rsa.

```py
import rsa
...
privatefile = 'myprivatekey.pem'
with open(privatekey,'r',) as privatefile:
    keydata = privatefile.read()
    privkey = rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(keydata,'PEM')
```

This gives me the error:

```
raise error.SubstrateUnderrunError('%d-octet short' % (length - len(substrate)))
pyasn1.error.SubstrateUnderrunError: 241258135299934072420413978887367113698521244196764765036638487009646022641423445372690412943975215342192406357926060763198896784236941481018430139761477591845142721555172078726675134842863273257382304489290139918678689615801729787593872634728755-octet short
```

If I leave "-des3" out of the openssl command, then the Python script runs perfectly. However, I need to password protect these private keys.

Can the python rsa library (https://pypi.org/project/rsa/) support these encrypted private keys? Or should I switch to a different library?

Comment: That RSA library is from the stone age. Try "Password-protected PKCS#8 key containers" in pycryptodome. That's what you likely get from the `openssl` command (but feel free to post a test key here so we can check).

Answer (score 0):

The exported key is a PEM encoded encrypted PKCS#1 key. Afaik, *Python-rsa* doesn't support encrypted keys, neither in PKCS#1 nor in PKCS#8 format. However, you can use *Cryptography* ([`load_pem_private_key()`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization/?highlight=key%20load#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.load_pem_private_key)) or - as suggested in the comment - *PyCryptodome* ([`import_key()`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/public_key/rsa.html?highlight=rsa%20key%20load#Crypto.PublicKey.RSA.import_key)).

The following Python Code shows the import of an encrypted PKCS#1 key with Cryptography and PyCryptodome:

```py
pkcs1_enc = b'''-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,2AE0CB6DF5DE68D3

6NRXk9JZDyV9RlaH5+HkT3PADPObPdUISVzFyHHB71vmdMoV8/Hazu2+xrZkkmPl
...
zrloBMa+B/WQm/rv3vbEw7BAnRZuAhlKuHt7/S7VfkWsB+XHSm9CiffcSqIxd02r
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'''

# Import/Export via Cryptography
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
keyViaHazmat = serialization.load_pem_private_key(pkcs1_enc, b'1234')
print(keyViaHazmat.private_bytes(serialization.Encoding.PEM, serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8, serialization.NoEncryption()).decode('utf-8'))

# Import/Export via PyCryptodome
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
keyViaPyCryptodome = RSA.import_key(pkcs1_enc, b'1234')
print(keyViaPyCryptodome.exportKey(format='PEM', passphrase=None, pkcs=8, protection=None).decode('utf-8'))
```

The code outputs the unencrypted PEM encoded PKCS#8 key.